# Find vertices of a convex polytope, defined by intersecting half-spaces

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

I am looking for a algorithm that returns the vertices of a polytope if provided with the set of intersecting half-spaces  that define it.

In my special case the polytope is constructed by the following constraints on $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$:

- $\sum_i x_i = 1$ (i.e., $\|x\|_1 = 1$).
- $0 \le a_i \leq x_i\leq b_i \leq1$, where the $a_i,b_i$ are given

This can either be thought of as the intersection of the hyper-plane (defined by the first constraint, in combination with the range restriction of the second constraint) with a hyper-cube (defined by the second constraint) or as the intersection of half-spaces where the first constraint is the intersection of two half-spaces that only intersect on a hyper-plane.

This always generates a convex polytope, if I am not mistaken, as long as the intersection creates a bounded set.

I would like to have an algorithm that returns the set vertices of the polytope if provided with the set of $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s.

There is a special case where there exists no $x$ that satifies this condition. Ideally, this would be picked up on.
Therefore, I would wish for an algorithm that checks if such a polytope exists and if so returns the vertices.

Comment: I sampled and [plotted](https://imgur.com/a/qam5BIv) the d=3 case, and it seems to support my argument.

Comment: Also I'm not really an expert on this topic, but my idea for enumerating the vertices would be that in a vertex, at most one $x_i$ is strictly between $a_i$ and $b_i$, and for all other $i$ it is that $x_i = a_i$ or $x_i = b_i$. Now you could fix the $i$ where $a_i < x_i < b_i$, and use some recursion with pruning to set other values to either $a_i$ or $b_i$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is a special case of enumerating the vertices of a convex polytope, and there is an efficient (polynomial-delay) recursive algorithm for your special case, which I will describe next.

If $a_1+\dots+a_d > 1$, then there is no solution, and you can terminate.  If $a_1+\dots+a_d=1$, there is a single solution $(a_1,\dots,a_d)$, so output it and terminate.  Otherwise, I'll assume $a_1+\dots+a_d < 1$, so you use the following:

- For each index $i$ such that $a_i<b_i$:

  - Let $c_i = 1-a_1-\dots-a_{i-1}-a_{i+1}-\dots-a_d$.
  - If $c_i \le b_i$, output $(a_1,\dots,a_{i-1},c_i,a_{i+1},\dots,a_d)$; it is a vertex of the original polytope.
  - Otherwise, replace $a_i \le x_i \le b_i$ with $b_i \le x_i \le b_i$ (i.e., replace $a_i$ with $b_i$) and recurse to output the vertices of the resulting polytope.

---

To help others find this by search: it's the intersection of the unit simplex (points of L1 norm exactly one) and an axis-aligned box.

---

In general, if the polytope is defined by an intersection $m$ half-spaces, then a vertex is defined by choosing a combination of $d$ out of the $n$ of the corresponding hyper-planes; if their intersection is a single point, and it is in the polytope, then it is a vertex.  This gives an exponential-time algorithm for enumerating all vertices for a general polytope.  There are other algorithms for the general case, but that's beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: You changed the question in such a way that it changed the problem. I require $\sum_i x_i = 1$ and not $\sum_i x_i \le 1$. You can not change the question just so you are able to answer it.

Comment: @ls., I apologize for that - it appears that I misunderstood what you were asking for.

Comment: @ls., I have revised my answer, and I believe it now answers the question you were asking, taking into account your comment.

Comment: As far as I understand it, this does not seem to be valid if $b_i<1$. Assume the following $\mathbb{R}^3$ case: $a_i=0$, $b_1<1$ and $b_{i≠1}=1$. Then $c_1 > b_1$. Therefore you would proceed with replacing replace $a_i$ and $b_i$ with $c_i=1$. Reducing the polytope onto the hyperplane $H:=\{x: x_1=c_1\}$. However, I would expect two "new" vertices (new compared to the "default" $b=1$ case) on the hyperplane $H:=\{x: x_1=b_1\}$. I feel like I misunderstood your answer somewhere.

Comment: Also, I do not see how your algorithm is able to produce more vertices then dimension. However, there exist cases where this is necessary

Comment: @ls., oops!  I had an error.  Try the revised answer.  You didn't misunderstand anything; I just wrote the wrong thing.  Now this projects onto the hyperplane $H := \{x:x_1=b_1\}$, exactly as you say.  Also, I hope the revised answer makes clear that this could potentially output far more vertices than the dimension (it could output exponentially many vertices, due to the recursion).

Answer (score 2):

In the following I will call $C:=\{x:\forall i.a_i\le x_i\le b_i\}$ the cuboid and $H:=\{x:\sum_i x_i=1\}$ the hyperplane.  I claim that all defining vertices of the polytope $C\cap H$ lie on the intersection of the $1$-dimensional skeleton $S:=\{x:\exists j.\forall i\neq j.x_i\in\{a_i,b_i\}\}$ with $H$, which can be evaluated by $\mathcal{O}(2^{d-1})$ operations (not very good, but still something, I guess).

A point $x$ is defining vertex of the polytope $P$ if and only if there is no non-zero $y$ and $\epsilon>0$ with $(x-\epsilon y,x+\epsilon y)\subseteq P$ (i.e. there is no axis along which $x$ can be moved in a small neighbourhood without leaving $P$).

Assume $x\in P$ doesn't lie in $S$, then w.l.o.g. $a_0<x_0<b_0$ and $a_1<x_1<b_1$.  So $e_1-e_0$ is an axis along which we can move $x$ without leaving $P$ and $x$ is no defining vertex of $P$.

On the other hand, assume $x\in P$ lies in $S$.  If $a_j<x_j<b_j$ then $e_j$ is the only axis along which we can move without leaving $S$, but moving along $e_j$ immedeately places us out of $H$, so $x$ is a defining vertex of $P$.  If all $x_i$ lie in $\{a_i,b_i\}$ then $x$ is even defining vertex of $C$ hence defining vertex of $P$ as well.

Comment: But those points lie at the skeleton, e.g. for $x=(0,0,1)$ we have with $j=2$ that $\forall i\neq j.x_i\in\{0,2\}$, or do I oversee something?

Comment: You're right.  I don't know what I was thinking.   Sorry.

Comment: I think this is true and would work. However, the scaling of $\mathcal{O}(2^{d-1})$ makes it infeasible (for my) higher dimensional problem.

Answer (score 2):

The [polymake](https://polymake.org) tool/library can do exactly what you asked for, if you are interested in a practical solution. See [here](https://polymake.org/doku.php/user_guide/tutorials/apps_polytope) for a brief tutorial.