# Algorithm for computing the vertices of a polytope defined as the intersection of half spaces

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, linear-algebra, graphics

There's a very similarly [sounding question with an answer already](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/119562/find-vertices-of-a-convex-polytope-defined-by-intersecting-half-spaces), but my setup is very, very different.

You are given $k$ half spaces in dimension $d$, defined by a point and a direction. You want to find all vertices in the polytope if it is bounded, otherwise, you want to close it (i.e. make it bounded), then find all vertices of your closure.

This differs from the prior question in that, the formulation is purely geometrical i.e. there is no assumption that the polytope is a simplex, no assumption about where it is in 3D space, no assumption about it being axis aligned in any way and no assumption as to the number of half planes that constitute it.